# Как после второго клика обнулить значения всех переменных?

Tags: javascript

**Помогите кто-нибудь, а то кранты!!!**

Есть контейнер с карточками.
**Нужно:**

1. после первого клика карточка выделяется;
2. после второго клика на второй карточке они (карточки) меняются местами с первой;
3. двумя следующими кликами выделяются новые пары карточек и меняются между собой;

   ```
   ... и тд. ...
   ```

---

**Что сделано:**

созданы два обработчика событий, которые находят две целевые карточки и меняют их местами, после этого обнуляются их переменные;
Казалось бы, все хорошо? Но!!! кликнутая карточка #2 почему-то не обнуляется и запоминается как первый клик! То есть, если в начале нажали по первой карточке, она сначала (как и нужно) перемещается на место нажатой вторым кликом, а если нажимают по третей карточке (чтобы поменять две новые пары карточек), то эта карточка перескакивает на место третьей, и так мигрирует по всему контейнеру после новых кликов :(((((
Пробовал обнулять селектор со всеми карточками, прекращал обработчики кликов - тогда скрипт перестает работать.

---

**Варианты решения проблемы:**

1. Может быть, прикрутить массив?
2. в конце скрипта обнулить селектор со всеми карточками и как-то (как?) потребовать возвратить текущее событие на начальный этап (м.б. при помощи `if cardAll = null {...}`).
3. Задать счетчик кликов, после второго клика обнулить все переменные? Приведите пожалуйста примеры.

P.S. Желательно, на чистом JS

```js
let cardHolder = document.querySelector('.offers__wrapper'),
cardAll = document.querySelectorAll('.card'),
cardItems = document.querySelectorAll('.card__comeback');

cardHolder.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    let star = e.target.closest('.card__comeback');
    let cardCurrent = e.target.closest('.card');

    if (star) {
        cardItems.forEach((item, i) => {
            if (item === star) {
                cardItems[i].classList.add("card__comeback--active");
                    if (cardCurrent) {
                        cardAll.forEach((item, i) => {
                            if (item === cardCurrent) {
                                let a = cardCurrent;
                                
                                cardHolder.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

                                    let star2 = e.target.closest('.card__comeback');
                                    let cardCurrent2 = e.target.closest('.card');
                            
                                    if (star2) {
                                        cardItems.forEach((item, i) => {
                                            if (item === star2) {
                                                cardItems[i].classList.add("card__comeback--active");
                                                    if (cardCurrent2) {
                                                        cardAll.forEach((item, i) => {
                                                            if (item === cardCurrent2) {
                                                                let b = cardCurrent2;
                                                                let temp;
                                                                temp = a.innerHTML;
                                                                a.innerHTML = b.innerHTML;
                                                                b.innerHTML = temp;
                                                                a = null; 
                                                                b = null;
                                                                temp = null;
                                                            };
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        };
                                });          
                            };
                        });
                    }
            } 
        });
    }; 
});
```

```html
<div class="offers__wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__img">
            <div class="card__for-sell">For Sell
            </div>
            <div class="card__hearth"></div>
            <div class="card__comeback"></div>
            <div class="card__type">Commercial Property
            </div>
            <img src="img/main/card/property-01.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <h3 class="card__title">Countryside Modern Lake View</h3>
        <div class="card__location">Poughkeepsie, New York</div>
        <div class="card__price">$28,000</div>
        <div class="card__conditions">
            <div class="beds">
                <div class="beds__icon"></div>
                <div class="amount">Beds 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="baths">
                <div class="baths__icon"></div>
                <div class="amount">Baths 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="square">
                <div class="square__icon"></div>
                <div class="amount">2200 Sqft</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь я правильно понял задачу, что вам нужно менять элементы местами.

Накидал такой вариант:

```js
let selected = false; // Тут будем хранить индекс первого выбранного элемента.

document.querySelector('.cards').addEventListener('click', e => { // Вешаем ивент на клик | делегирование
  const target = e.target.closest('.cards-item'); // Получаем элемент для перемещения
  if(target) { // Проверяем что такой есть - это для делегирования
  
    // Если нажат будет тот, который уже выделен, то мы снимем с него класс и отменим действие
    if(target.classList.contains('cards-item-selected')) {
      target.classList.remove('cards-item-selected');
      selected = false;
      return false;
    }
    
    // А тут основная логика
    if(selected === false) { // Если нет индекса первого выброного элемента
      selected = [...target.parentElement.children].indexOf(target); // получаем этот индекс и сразу записываем
      
      target.classList.add('cards-item-selected'); // Вешаем ему класс, чтобы выделить
    } else { // А тут будет действие для второго выделеного блока
      const parent = target.parentElement; // Получаем родителя
      const i = [...parent.children].indexOf(target); // Получаем индекс второго нажатого блока
      const childrens = parent.children; // Получаем все блоки
      
      const clones = [childrens[selected].cloneNode(true), childrens[i].cloneNode(true)]; // Чтобы проще было поменять, мы клонируем наши выбранные элементы. Таким способом сохронятся даже повешанные на них ивенты.

      // Далее логика такая: заменяем А клоном Б, а Б клоном А.
      parent.replaceChild(clones[0], childrens[i]);
      parent.replaceChild(clones[1], childrens[selected]);
      
      childrens[i].classList.remove('cards-item-selected'); // Удаляем класс выделения
      // P.s. удаляем класс не у selected, а у i, потому что под этими индексами уже поменяные элементы.
      selected = false; // Указываем что "выбранный" - не выбран.
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 180px; 
}

.cards-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cards-item-selected {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #09f;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="cards-item">1</div>
  <div class="cards-item">2</div>
  <div class="cards-item">3</div>
  <div class="cards-item">4</div>
  <div class="cards-item">5</div>
  <div class="cards-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Код на ES6, если важно)

Comment: De.Minov огромное спасибо!!! Так быстро, с такими подробными пояснениями! Вы - золотой человек!

Comment: @Игорь00073, рад помочь. Если мой ответ помог вам, вы можете отметить его галочкой (слева от ответа), это будет хорошей благодарностью для меня)